# Fabric suddenly shows 0 values

Tags: google-fabric, crashlytics-android

From today morning, fabric dashboard has started showing 0 values in our android application.

So right now it shows 0 Daily Active users, 0 Daily New Users, 0% Adoption of our latest version. 0.0 Median total time spent in app. Just the active users is non zero.

This is started to happen in our Android app and not in other apps on fabric.

For info: 
The crashlytics version we are using right now is 1.1.60 (`com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:1.1.60@aar`), will update it to latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to a temporary issue we saw and should no longer be affecting any dashboards. Thanks!

Comment: It happens again this morning after I upgraded my app version.